# How can I disable the ng-click event for a span?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
<span class="fa fa-minus-square-o"
    ng-click="wos.word(xxx)"
    ng-disabled="cursorWait"
    ng-hide="wos.wordFormRowIsDisabled(wf)"></span>
```

Is there a way that I could stop the ng-click having any effect if cursorWait == true?  I know disabled won't work :-)

Comment: From within the `wos.word()` function, check if cursorWait === true.  `if($scope.cursorWait === true) return;`  You'd also need to style it accordingly:  `ng-class="cursorWait ? 'disabled-class' : 'normal-class'"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing `ng-click="!cursorWait && wos.word(xxx)"` will probably work. Not sure about what you are trying to achieve here. Why not using a button ?

Comment: I'm using a font-awesome + or -.  A button is a bit too big for this part of the UI.  Thanks